# Content Under Sliding Drawer - Android

Tags: java, android, layout, button, slidingdrawer

I'm having trouble getting this button to only appear under the drawer. I'm using a package that I found online and not the sliding drawer that comes with the SDK.

Here is the main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_open"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ns:content="@+id/content"
        ns:direction="topToBottom"
        ns:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <include
            android:id="@id/content"
            layout="@layout/pen_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
    </it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in case it will help, here is the pen_content.xml layout that is included:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern1"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/option1"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bar_size"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SeekBar>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#FF999999" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/option2"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bar_alpha"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SeekBar>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#FF999999" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/option3"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bar_blur"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SeekBar>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#FF999999" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_close"
                    android:text="@string/close"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_above="@id/layout01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:background="#FF999999" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are screenshots of how it acts now (the first is when the slider is open, the second is closed). You can see how the button remains visible when the slider is open. I want it to only be visible on the layout behind the drawer. Thanks!

[image: Open State]

[image: Closed State]

Comment: It looks like you have an extra button in there called `button_open` Its not part of the drawer as far as I can tell. Try deleting that/altering the text to see which one it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088826/slider-in-android-app/9287885#9287885) and it will Surly help you a lot. . . .

**Updated**

It seems that you are using the example that i have given in the link. Anyways you just have to set the transperancy of the slidingDrawer layout. Just see the code proper and set the transperancy and it will solve your issue.

Enjoy Coading. :)